# Chartkick yAxis and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

Please can anyone help me with this issue?
I have A ruby on rails app and I am trying to use ChartKick.
I have the following code in my Controller to get all Publications:

`@mentor_pub = Publication.all.where(user: current_user).order("mentor ASC")`

And I am using the code below in my views.

```
<%= column_chart @mentor_pub.group(:mentor).count, height: "600px",   discrete: true%>
```

[You can see the image of what I am talking about here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaLLj.png)

the chart is displaying the way I want it, but The Yaxis is displaying decimal numbers instead of integers.
Please How would I modify the Yaxis to show integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chartkick uses Google Visualization under the hood and allows you to pass options directly to the library using the `library` option like so:

```
<%= line_chart data, library: {backgroundColor: "#eee"} %>
```

for your exact problem you'll have to look into Googles documentation or this stackoverflow answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16036721/390977 might help.